# Change breadcrumb titles in Drupal 8

Tags: drupal-8

It is possible to change titles of breadcrumb links.

I tried it using hook_system_breadcrumb_alter() like:

```
$breadcrumb_links = $breadcrumb->getLinks();
$breadcrumb_links[0] = \Drupal\Core\Link::createFromRoute(t('schnellinfo'), '');
```

With this code, able to get all links and set set title of first link. But don't know how to assign it.

Comment: you are doing this in a module?

Comment: Yes, I was doing this in a module. But now manage to do in template.php

Answer (score -1):

```
$breadcrumb_links = $breadcrumb->getLinks();
  if (!empty($breadcrumb_links)) {
    $breadcrumb_links[0]->setText('texto');
  }
```